# NSFetchedResultController Questions

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm currently using NSFetchedResultController to get the to displayed data.
However I've got two question about it:

1) When I set the fetchSizeBatch property to 2, my app always crashes.
   What does fetchSizeBatch actually mean? I don't really want to set it to 2, I was just        playing with it and noticed that bug.

2) My app currently uses about 25 MB of memory while scrolling through the UITableView. I assume NSFetchedResultController is causing that. Is 25 MB still normal? Or is this controller some sort of device specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two is an extremely low number for a Core Data batch size.  [According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize), which probably explains it much better than I do, setting a batch size means that the data will be processed in batches; in other words, Core Data queries the database for the sorted results but only pulls the amount specified by the batch size into managed objects.  The implementation of this - and this is the big part - is a proxy subclass of NSArray which will page in items from each batch whenever they're accessed, either by index, enumeration, whatever.  In your case, this means that Core Data is taking a round trip back to the database every two objects.   For an NSFetchedResultsController talking to a UITableView, you can see how much of a problem this is.

Otherwise, 25MB isn't fantastic, but I've seen apps do much worse.  I would say you're good.

Comment: Well, is there a way to make these 25MBs less using the NSFetchedResultController? Thanks for the explanation!